# AWS ECS replace Environment Variable in a Dockerize Angular App

Tags: angular, docker, amazon-ecs

I am trying to update/override an environment variable in a dockerized angular app inside an AWS ECS task definition.

In Spring Boot I declare the variable and override it in AWS ECS Task Definition and is working OK:

```
@Value("${APP_ONE_URI:http://localhost:8010/api/stock/}")
    private String url;
...
ResponseEntity<Stock> stockEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(url + "{stock}", Stock.class, getUriVariables(instrument));
```

I would like to do the same thing in the Angular App.
What is the best practice to declare the variable in Angular so I can override it in AWS ECS Task Definition?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can not access the system environment variable in an angular app. Keep one thing in mind, you will only be able to **inject environment variables before your Angular app builds**. Unlike Nodejs, you will not get real-time access because you are running in a browser environment.

So the way around is to build the app when the container started, then you will able to access the task definition environment variable.

You can check this [link](https://www.bennettnotes.com/post/angular-read-system-environment-variables/) to inject environment variable at build time.